# Nearest intersections outside the polygon in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, intersection, network

I have two layers, a street network and a polygon, and I want to find the nearest street intersection points just outside the boundary of the polygon. For example some area is closed by police and I want to find all the intersections where they have to divert traffic.

Is there any easy solution in ArcGIS 10.2, please?

The result should be a point layer of the nearest intersections outside of the polygon.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to address:  "Nearest" with respect to what?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use analysis-intersect of street network on itself (single input), specify output as point. Select points inside polygon, switch selection. Use spatial join (closest) of points to polygon, select DISTANCE field. The point with minimum distance is your answer.

Comment: Chris, thats exactly what I am after, thanks. I am trying to solve problem that some area is closed by police and want to find all the intersectins where they have to divert traffic.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select by location all street lines that *cross the boundary* of
   your polygon.
2. Use [Feature Vertices to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003p000000) (requires an Advanced license)
   on the selected lines with the BOTH_ENDS option. Since line
   direction isn't guaranteed to be consistent in crossing your polygon
   boundary, you need both ends of the street line.
3. Select by location all of the created points that intersect/are
   within the polygon boundary and delete them. The remaining points
   should be the intersections just outside the polygon boundary that
   you seek.

Note this solution assumes that your street lines are all broken into segments at each (valid) intersection. If not, the vertices to points step won't work correctly. If you don't have an Advanced license, there are some other methods to generate the points discussed in other questions here if you search, along with a few third-party extensions like [ET Geotools](http://www.ian-ko.com/) that can do it.